# Phonegap + Crosswalk - disabled pull to refresh effect

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I connected to the project on phonegap - plugin Crosswalk WebView Engine. This will effect reload/ refresh application when we pull the screen down. How can I disable this effect?

In his file config.xml tried to add the line:

```
<preference name="CROSSWALK_ANDROID_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
```

or

```
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
```

or

```
<preference name="xwalk-command-line" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
```

None of the options did not give any result.
I compiles the application through service - "Adobe Phonegap Build" if it has any importance.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, so i forked the cordova crosswalk webview plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt . My plugin is based on xwalk_core_lib 16.45.417.

If you want to use it, add this line to your config.xml file :

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-pgb-adapt" source="npm" version="1.4.0-dev-5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install the cordova crosswalk plugin by the option of "--variable" like
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --variable CROSSWALK_ANDROID_COMMANDLINE="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect --disable-overscroll-edge-effect" after merging the commit https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/pull/41.

Answer (score 0):

CrossWalk supports all of the command lines of **Chromium**. So what you should do is just using `-disable-pull-to-refresh-effect`. (The more to see http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

There are two way to use command lines in your own project.

1. use command options like `-disable-pull-to-refresh-effect` in make_apk.py script
2. add a file named `xwalk-command-line` in your assets dictory, writing the command lines with the format: `xwalk --disable-pull-to-refresh-effect`

See also with:  https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-website/wiki/Use-Chromium-command-lines-in-your-apps-on-Android

Hope that helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

> You might want to fork the Crosswalk plugin with those modifications and upload it on PhoneGap Build (if you're a subscriber) or on NPM, if you need those modifications.

[from Phonegap build Official Rep](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/crosswalk-plugin-disable-pull-to-refresh)